# Python Standard Deviation on a Deque

Tags: python, deque, moving-average, standard-deviation

I am computing the simple moving average using the Python deque datatype, and I am wondering is there a way to have it treat this as some sort of an array and find the standard deviation of the deque?

Comment: Would help if you added a concrete example of what you want.  You can apply `list()` to a deque to get a plain list with the same values in the same order.  Is that enough?  Or do you also need code to calculate sdev?  Etc.

Comment: You can iterate over a deque and you can get its length. What more do you need?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it was that clear I ended up doing something like dlist[n] and iterating over that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can treat a *deque* as an array. It is both iterable and indexable :-)

Here's an example of computing a moving average and moving standard deviation with a sliding window of width five:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> from collections import deque
>>> from statistics import mean, stdev

>>> window = deque((randrange(100) for i in range(5)), 5)
>>> print(mean(window), stdev(window))
55.4 30.104816890325043
>>> for i in range(10):
        x = randrange(100)
        window.append(x)
        print(mean(window), stdev(window))

49.4 26.782456944798774
42.8 28.74369496080836
53 19.557607215607945
44.6 15.208550226763892
44.2 14.75466028073842
37.4 18.716303053755034
47.4 22.142718893577637
36.2 29.609120216581918
29.2 33.80384593504118
30 34.66266002487403
```

For larger windows, it is possible to compute moving averages and standard deviations more efficiently by keeping running totals.  See [this blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) by John Cook.
The *deque* makes it easy to update the running total by quickly accessing both the element is being evicted and the element being:

```
>>> window = deque((randrange(100) for i in range(5)), 5)
>>> for i in range(10):
        print(window, end='\t')
        old = window[0]
        new = randrange(100)
        window.append(new)
        print(f'Out with the {old}. In with the {new}')

deque([8, 53, 59, 86, 34], maxlen=5)    Out with the 8. In with the 58
deque([53, 59, 86, 34, 58], maxlen=5)   Out with the 53. In with the 81
deque([59, 86, 34, 58, 81], maxlen=5)   Out with the 59. In with the 31
deque([86, 34, 58, 81, 31], maxlen=5)   Out with the 86. In with the 21
deque([34, 58, 81, 31, 21], maxlen=5)   Out with the 34. In with the 11
deque([58, 81, 31, 21, 11], maxlen=5)   Out with the 58. In with the 91
deque([81, 31, 21, 11, 91], maxlen=5)   Out with the 81. In with the 42
deque([31, 21, 11, 91, 42], maxlen=5)   Out with the 31. In with the 97
deque([21, 11, 91, 42, 97], maxlen=5)   Out with the 21. In with the 94
deque([11, 91, 42, 97, 94], maxlen=5)   Out with the 11. In with the 29
```